# How to set default installation dir for MSI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer

Using VS2010.  I have a VS Installer project.  I've [learned](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419133515/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0z89y5d.aspx) how to set the default install dir according to a registry value.

But, I need to add logic so that if there is no such RegKey, then fall back onto the default [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName] as the default install dir.

Hoping to not need WiX for this (due to time constraints and learning curve).

This is my first post.  Please correct me if I haven't followed the guidelines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through a [type 51 custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368237%28VS.85%29.aspx) (property set with formatted). Basically, you set the folder property to the default path when that property is empty.

Since this needs to be done before CostInitialize, you will need to either edit the MSI with Orca to move the custom action or use WiX to configure the action manually.

Either way, make sure that this custom action is [immediate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368069%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, at least now I'm sure it can't be done natively in VS.  

Thanks.

Comment: RE: _when that property is empty_  
  
  
Hm, is there a way to add logic like that in Orca?  I don't see where.